# Google reCaptcha just checked it automaticaly

Tags: recaptcha, captcha

I implemented Google reCaptcha V2 in our website.
One of our client have been checked by reCaptcha as soon the page loaded.
He just didnt click to verify, the reCaptcha just checked it automaticaly

Does anybody know what this is or how to resolve it?

Tks,

André

Answer (score 0):

I made some tests and i found a certificate installed in user windows machine.

I think that there are some situations that Google check recaptcha automatically, based in trusted user.

Tks